# Ember association returns class instead of instance

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using `Ember 1.13`, `Ember data 1.13`.

Whenever I do `findRecord` to send a request to an api endpoint, all the information gets returned correctly and is placed into the store correctly which I can view in `Ember-inspector/data`.

Then when I try to get an association from the main model that I requested, it gives me back a `Class` instead of an `instance` even though I can see in `Ember-inspector/data` that the association and both models are there.

`ember-inspector`
[image]

request code:

```
var business = this.store.findRecord('business', 1);
```

I've also tried with a then function:

```
this.store.findRecord('business', 1).then(function(business) {};
```

Then I try and get the association:

```
var businessPreference = business.get('businessPreference');
```

This returns a class:

```
Class {__ember1441932015632: null, __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object}
```

And gives me undefined if I try and get a property from it

```
businessPreference.get('cancellationWindow');
undefined
```

Notes: I am currently trying this in a `component`. I have injected the `store` in order to do this. It was also doing the same thing from the `model hook` but was correctly returning the association in the `afterModel hook` which is very strange.

**UPDATE:** 
We are using `JSONAPIAdapter` and `JSONAPISerializer`.

`business model`
[image]

`businessPreference model`
[image]

Here is the response returned from api. This is `JSONAPI 1.0` compliant. We added `normalizeResponse` function to `JSONAPISerializer` to immediately return the `JSONAPI` payload

[image]

Comment: Try `var business = this.store.findRecord('business', 1).toJSON();` - http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON - to get the JSON representation. Not ideal (there may be another method to extract the relationship directly)

Comment: Please share code for model definition and sample return data from API. Also, you use REST or JSONAPI adapter?

Comment: @DanielKmak Ok I added those to the question. Thank you

Comment: I moved the logic out of the component to the top level controller and I changed all the async to false in the models and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try`let business = this.store.findRecord('business', 1).then(function(business) {return business;});` That should return the model to the variable once the promise resolves...